# How to match the decimal digits which equals 0 at the end of a number in Regex?

Tags: regex, decimal

I want to remove the zeros at the end of a number coming after the decimal point. To give an example:

> 12.009000 should match "000"

I have the regex pattern below but it gives an error `A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width` and I can't find any solution to fix that. What is the correct pattern to match successfully?

**Pattern**: `(?<=\.[0-9]*)0+$`

Comment: Perhaps this: https://regex101.com/r/kTa0Ec/1

Comment: How about: https://regex101.com/r/NvUm1n/1

Comment: You can use this: \d+\.([1-9]*|0(?!0+$))*

Comment: For regex it's super important to know what the rest of the data looks like (the stuff you *aren't* trying to match). For example, is the input string always a single number, or are the numbers inside a larger string? If the latter, what kind of text is in the string? Do all numbers have digits to the left of the `.`? Also, regex varies a little bit by language/software, so it's helpful to know what programming/software context you're in.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. Get the value into a numeric variable and truncate it there. One instruction.

Answer (score 1):

With Java, you can do it like this.

- `(\\d)` capture digits
- followed by 0's
- replace with the captured digits.
- `$1` is the back reference to the capture group

```
    str = str.replaceAll("(\\.\\d+?)0+$","$1");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Note: It will leave 12.000000 as 12.0.

Comment: this doesnt work correct for numbers without decimal places e.g 100

Comment: True.  I was answering the question the way it was written.

Comment: @AliTor I think I fixed it (probably a bit late but it was fun).

Answer (score 1):

```
   (\d+[.]?\d*?)0*$
   One more step is needed to replace the dot for numbers such as 12.000
```

Click here for demo: [Click Here](https://regex101.com/r/8i9nSP/1)

Or to deal with numbers such as 12.000 in one step:

```
   (?:(\d+)\.0*$)|(?:(\d+[.]?\d*?)0*$)
```

Click here for demo: [Click Here](https://regex101.com/r/ovhBA2/1)

Comment: It still fails for .5000

Comment: That is easy to cover if there is such a case. Just make the digits before the decimal optional by adding a "?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is [my attempt](https://regex101.com/r/NvUm1n/3):

```
(?:[.][0-9]*[1-9])(0+)$|([.]0+$)
```

This assumes that the input string is actually a number (it won't protect against things like xyz.001). It will not match at all if there are no trailing zeros after decimal point; and if there are, it removes:

1. sequence of `0`s preceded by a `[1-9]` after `[.][0-9]*`

or

2. a `[.]` followed by a sequence of `0`s.

   The result will always be in the captured group if the regex matches.

Answer (score -2):

```
([\d.]+?)(0*)
```

"Find digits and dots, but not greedily, then find trailing zeros"

Group 1 is the number. Group 2 is the trailing zeros.